# How to retrieve image from sqlce database and place on picture box

Tags: vb.net, image, sql-server-ce

I have never worked with images before, this is my first time. I am trying to write a procedure that retrives the image based on a product ID.  I did it the same I would retrieve a string but I am getting the following error on one of my lines:

```
Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataTable'
```

Here is my code:

```
        Try

        'Set variables to get values
        Dim strCatId As String = txtCategoryName.Text
        **Dim table As DataTable = PRODUCT_CATEGORYTableAdapter.GetCategoryImage(strCatId) 'I get the error here**

        Dim imgCategory As Image = CType(table.Rows(0)("Image"), Image)

        'Send value to picturebox
        picCategoryImage.Image = imgCategory

        'Update last assigned items
        table.Rows.Clear()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Because I have never worked with images, I really don't know how to solve this issue.  Can someone help me on going about fixing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a function but this one is for WPF. Just change the ImageSource to Image in Windows Forms.

```
 public static ImageSource CreateImage(string path)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Image finalImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();

        try
        {
            img.BeginInit();
            img.StreamSource = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        }

        catch 
        {
            return null;
        }

        finally
        {
            img.EndInit();
            finalImage.Source = img;

        }

        return finalImage.Source;
    }

}
```

The Idea is write the Image to a file. Then convert it to BitMap Image